# How to load pages without user interruption?

Tags: java, html, load, wicket

I am Dnyani wagh and working on Java wicket framework. I am working on Inventory Manangement
System.In this system I generate Bill form but it required some time to load.
Now my problem is at a time of form  loading, if user click any where on screen, loading process get affected. I want to load bill form and user are not able access my system at a time of bill loading.
Please give me some advice or guideline how i can achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really think that blocking user's input is a really good idea. For example, I cannot remember any web service, which does that. However, if you really want, you may show Wicket's [ModalWindow](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html) with close button disabled. Here is also [an example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/modal-window) with a source code:

This code will block modal window's close button

```java
modal1.setCloseButtonCallback(new ModalWindow.CloseButtonCallback() {
    public boolean onCloseButtonClicked(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        return false;
    }
});
```